# justify link text following an image icon when it wraps

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a link with link icon on the left, and an arrow to the right. What I am having problem with is as the link text wraps, it doesn't justify very well. How can I achieve something like here http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3xbfyqkh/, but with my given markup?

```
<div class="linkitem" id="myTools" style=
"display:inline-block; padding:4px 0 4px 0; width:90%;">
    <a href="{$ItemEditURL}" id="InlineEditLink" style=
    "cursor: pointer; position:relative; top: 4px; margin-right:5px;"><img height="14"
    src=
    "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Android_L/PNG/24/Programming/edit_property-24.png"
    title="Edit" width="14"></a> <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" style=
    "color: white !important!" target="_blank" title="{@LinkToolTip}">A
    very long descriptive Link text goes here</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapperArrow" style="float:right; padding-top:5px;"><img alt=""
src=
"https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/16/Arrows/double_right-16.png"></div><br>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<hr>
Free Icons provided by <a href="https://icons8.com">Icons8</a>
```

My fiddle here...
https://jsfiddle.net/a2gruae6/

Comment: What is the difference between the samples that you provided?

Comment: The main difference is shown on the paragraph when you resize. The starting point of the new line is after the icon on the first fiddle, and directly below the icon on the second fiddle. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update this code in your inline style as solve your problem

```
<div class="linkitem" id="myTools" style=
    "display:inline-block; padding:4px 0 4px 0; width:90%;">
        <a href="{$ItemEditURL}" id="InlineEditLink" style=
        "cursor: pointer;position: absolute;float:left;width:20px;"><img height="14"
        src=
        "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Android_L/PNG/24/Programming/edit_property-24.png"
        title="Edit" width="14"></a> <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" style=
        "color: white !important!;float:left;margin-left: 20px;" target="_blank" title="{@LinkToolTip}">A
        very long descriptive Link text goes here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapperArrow" style="float:right; padding-top:5px;"><img alt=""
    src=
    "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/windows10/PNG/16/Arrows/double_right-16.png"></div><br>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <hr>
    Free Icons provided by <a href="https://icons8.com">Icons8</a>
```

Comment: Please take the time to _explain_ what the problem is and why your solution works. Code only answers are not generally useful and could be voted down.